# Jquery Datepicker - Set Max and Min value based on input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My jQuery:

```
$('#begindate').datepicker();
$('#enddate').datepicker();
```

The Begin and the enddate date shall not exceed the Date today.

And the enddate must not be before the begindate.

How do I set these limits with jquery datepicker?

Example if you first set the enddate, then the begindate limit would be the date enddate is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range ?

see the example http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/date-range.html

and for your request you can combine with http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max